# Not able to deploy code with salesforce DX when using office network

Tags: deployment, salesforce

I am not able to deploy code with salesforce dx when using office network but it works perfectly fine when working with the home network, I have followed all the steps mentioned in the below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli

also tried creating environment variables as below with right credentials and proxy

> Variable    Value HTTP_PROXY 
>   http://:@proxy.company.com:8080 HTTPS_PROXY
>   http://:@proxy.company.com:8080

after wasting days on the same I still get the below error

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 101.51.149.128:413

Comment: Questions that are very Salesforce-specific are best asked on [Salesforce StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I didn't get an answer to this problem there

Comment: That's unfortunate. Based on your description of the issue, it might be a problem with the proxy or it might be an issue with sfdx CLI not interfacing with the proxy correctly. These types of problems are difficult to diagnose without an intimate knowledge of all the moving parts. Do you have a Salesforce subscription / contract? If so, we recommend you [open a case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329621&type=1&mode=1) with SF.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue in our office network, and found out that the sfdx cli recognizes the lowercase variables only. For us it worked setting them up as `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.